# XAMPP issue: php_value include_path not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-redirect

I can't get `php_value include_path` to work with XAMPP. It seems as though it should be an easy to solve problem, but have been searching and trying for hours.

Modifying the root in Apache's/XAMPP's `httpd.cfg` works like a charm, but attempting to do the same in the `.htaccess` file simply doesn't. Here's my full `.htaccess` file (everything works except this aspect):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
rewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

## Hide .php extension by external redirection:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC]

## Internally redirect to .php extension:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products/.*$

## Redirect to index when page is missing.
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.xxxxx.xxx

php_value include_path ".:D:/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/project1"
```

I've tried endless variations:

```
".:D:\Applications\XAMPP\htdocs\project1"

.:D:/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/project1

".:/project1"
```

And all variations of this. I simply can't figure it out. Anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In windows you use a `;` and not a `:` as a seperator in path statements, so try

```
php_value include_path ".;D:/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/project1"
```